# how can i code discord bot to delete "user pinned a message" message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i attempted coding using python for my discord bot to automatically delete the "user pinned a message to this channel..." message every time someone pins a message to the channel but it's not working and i cannot figure out why :( please help if u can? tysm <3

**my problem**:
the bot is not deleting "**user** pinned **a message** to this channel. see all **pinned messages**." message when i pin a msg

**this is my code**: what i tried :v

```py
if message.type == "PINS_ADD" and message.author.bot: 
   await message.delete()
```

what am i doing wrong?
i have to add that i am a beginner so-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`message.author.bot` is only True if the message is written by the Bot himself. Since the message you like to delete is a System message, this is not the case

just remove it and it should work

```py
if message.type is discord.MessageType.pins_add:
   await message.delete()

# or i think this would also work
if str(message.type) == "pins_add"
    await message.delete()
```

Comment: `Message.type` returns a `MessageType` instance, you cannot really compare it to a string, `if message.type is discord.MessageType.pins_add:` should work though.

Comment: okok that makes sense, but i changed the code to `if discord.MessageType.pins_add: await message.delete()` and the bot deletes every message that is sent rather than the pinned one @ŁukaszKwieciński

Comment: OHHH wait nvm excuse my little misunderstanding, i changed it to `if message.type is discord.MessageType.pins_add:` and it works thank uu :) @ŁukaszKwieciński

Comment: ah yeah I forgot that ^^